# unlink associated image from php

Tags: php

I am trying to unlink specified image which is linked with mysql table  record ID.I can delete the record on mysql. I get Internal server error when i run this script,

Query:

I have two cameras  in_cam and out_cam folders I am trying to swap lane the images from in_cam to out_cam my script copies the images from in_cam to out_cam but the image is not deleted in the in_cam.

```
 Put the entry into the other table
            $sql = "INSERT INTO $newCamTable (plate, nread, datetime, millisecs, nationality, image_name,image) SELECT plate, nread, datetime, millisecs, nationality, image_name,image  FROM $camTable $
            logit($sql);
            $result = $conn->Execute($sql);
            if (!$result)
              {
                print $conn->ErrorMsg();
              }

            $sql = "SELECT id FROM $newCamTable ORDER BY id DESC";
            $result = $conn->Execute($sql);
            if (!$result)
              {
                print $conn->ErrorMsg();
              }
            $row = $result->fields;
            $newId = $row['id'];

            $sql = "UPDATE $newCamTable SET name=\"$new_cam_name\", camera_id=\"$new_cam_id\" WHERE id=\"$newId\"";
            logit($sql);
            $result = $conn->Execute($sql);
            if (!$result)
              {
                print $conn->ErrorMsg();
              }
    This is what I AM TRYING TO DO.

            sql = """SELECT id FROM  $camTable where id = \"$tableEntryId\"  LIMIT 1";
            logit($sql);
            $result  = $conn->Execute($sql);
            $id =  etCommonGetImagePath($conn, $camName, $id) {
            $serverDir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
            $imagesTop = "/cam_images";

            $idArray = str_split(strval($id));
            $idString = implode('/', $idArray);

            $webPath = $imagesTop . "/" . $camName . "/" . $idString . ".jpg";
            $full_path = $serverDir . $webPath;

            if (file_exists($full_path)) {
            unlink($idString);
            }*/


            // Delete the entry from the camera table
            $sql = "DELETE FROM $camTable WHERE id=\"$tableEntryId\" LIMIT 1";
            logit($sql);
            $result = $conn->Execute($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to use the path on your server to delete the image, not the url.

```
unlink('/var/www/test/folder/images/image_name.jpeg');
```

Comment: the image is asccoiated with ID in mysql

Comment: So what do you want ?

Answer (score 0):

The following should help

realpath — Returns canonicalized absolute pathname
 is_readable — Tells whether a file exists and is readable
 unlink — Deletes a file

Run your filepath through realpath, then check if the returned path exists and if so, unlink it.